# DHCP Windows Server can create multiple scope same subnet?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp

I have one server DHCP Windows Server 2012 R2. Can I create the scopes :

```
Scope A : 10.10.10.11 - 10.10.10.30  
Scope B : 10.10.10.31 - 10.10.10.55  
Scope C : 10.10.10.56 - 10.10.10.105  
Scope D : 10.10.10.106 - 10.10.11.254  

subnet mask : 255.255.254.0
```

Is it possible? 
Any ideas/feedback?

thx a lot ya

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You would get an error that your address range and mask conflicts with another scope with your settings.

[image: Scope test]

I think you should revisit your scope settings (mask vs. IP):
[image: Suggestion]

Now, I don't know the rest of your network setup, so I can't come with a better suggestion, but it will work with the Windows DHCP :)

Comment: okay thx your information. I want to try and I share you for any update.